# how to write synced-cron job that executes 20 seconds later - SyncedCron Meteor

Tags: meteor, cron, laterjs

I want to create a synced-cron job which runs only once and the execution time will be 20 seconds later as soon as the job is created. How would I write the parser?

Comment: If you need it to run only once, couldn't a simple `Meteor.setTimeout(job, 20000)` suffice?

Comment: that wouldn't serve my purpose. I need to execute something on server.

Comment: You can use `percolate:synced-cron` package and use `parser.text('every 20 seconds')` then control how to stop the job using `SyncedCron.stop()`

Answer (score 4):

[Meteor.setTimeout can be run on the server](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_settimeout)

If you want something that runs 20 seconds after server startup, you can do this

```
if(Meteor.isServer){

    var job = function(){};

    Meteor.startup(function(){
        Meteor.setTimeout(job, 20000);
    });
}
```

If you are set on using synced-cron, you can use `SyncedCron.remove(jobName)`. See Advanced section of [Synced Cron Docs](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron)

```
if(Meteor.isServer){

    SyncedCron.add({
        name: 'Run in 20 seconds only once',
        schedule: function(parser) {
            // parser is a later.parse object
            return parser.text('every 20 seconds');
        },
        job: function() {
            // do something important here

            SyncedCron.remove('Run in 20 seconds only once');
        }
    });

    Meteor.startup(function(){
        SyncedCron.start();
    });

}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [doc](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron):

> To schedule a once off (i.e not recurring) event, create a job with a
>   schedule like this `parser.recur().on(date).fullDate();`

So you can set something like `parser.recur().on(new Date()+1000*20).fullDate()` to execute the job once.